# binary multiplication in 2 parts

Tags: assembly, x86, binary, x86-64

When I take a binary value and split this value into two parts. E.g.:
11110000 -> 1111 | 0000

My goal ist to multiply this value - split into two - with another value e.g. 1010.

When I multiply 11110000 with 1010 I get

```
   00000000
  11110000
 00000000
11110000 
-----------
100101100000
```

but how do I get this result when partially multiplying the 1111 and then 0000 with 1010 (or any other such partial binary multiplication). The reason I have to understand this is that I have two 64 bit numbers in x86-64 assembly and must multiply them with another 64-bit register.

Comment: Multiply the two halves, add the results using the appropriate parts. Note that x86-64 has multiplication that provides double width result.

Comment: Are you asking about the math behind multi work arithmetic (multiplication), or about the x86-64 instruction set?

Comment: If you have 64-bit registers, you should just use `mul rcx` to do `RDX:RAX = rcx * rax`.  It would be pointless to split them into 32-bit halves and then do four widening `mul` instructions (or four `imul r64, r64` instructions) and a bunch of adds.

Comment: I assume they are trying to do a 128*64 multiply.

Answer (score 1):

You can think about this in decimal, if it helps you.

When you try to multiply two numbers you can exploit the associativity of multiplication, hence `a(b+c) = ab + ac`.

So if you want to multiply, say

`9876 x 12`

you know that

`9876 = 98*100 + 76`

and finally

`(98*100 + 76)*12 = 98*12*100 + 76*12`

But multiplying by 10^x in base ten is shifting by x to the right, hence:

`9876 x 12 = (12*98) << 2  + 12*76`

A pseudo code for this could then be:

```
op1 <= 0b11110000  // operand 1
op2 <= 0b1010      // operand 2

split1 = AND   ( op1   , 0xf0 ) // 0b11110000 = 240 
split1 = RSHIFT( split1, 4    ) // 0b1111 = 15
split2 = AND   ( op2   , 0x0f ) // 0b0000 = 0

// Take care of overflow!
part1  = MUL   ( split1, op2  ) //  0b1111 * 0b1010 = 0b10010110 = 150
part1  = LSHIFT( part1 , 4    ) //  0b100101100000  = 2400
part2  = MUL   ( split2, op2  ) //  0b0000 * 0b1010 = 0b0000

res    = SUM   ( part1 , part2) //  0b100101100000   = 2400
```